# Steam and related services use bad certificates

Tags: steam

I can't use any of the steam services related to my steam account.

I get (as a for instance)

```
https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/35221031620730505/

Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the 
server’s certificate.

HTTP Strict Transport Security: false

HTTP Public Key Pinning: false
```

I can still play CS:GO without problems.
My steam client says Error -107 which is curiously devoid of Google hits.

How do I debug this?

Is this a problem on my end or theirs?

Firefox reports the error as

```
SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN
```

My steam client has now replaced the error -107 with

```
Invalid SSL Certificate
```

Comment: A common reason why SSL certificates fail is an incorrect system time that doesn't match the certificate. Double check your system time and date, as well as the bios time and date. Maybe also try setting your preferred DNS to Google's 8.8.8.8 to fix possible domain name issues.

Answer (score -1):

The solution I found to this problem was to enter steam web page on a computer that can access the web page, then export the certificates being used and later import them to the computer having the problem.